# Cannot apply dashboard filter from chart "Table" on Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

According to [this](https://github.com/apache-superset/superset-ui/pull/344), I should be able to emit filter events from a 'Table' chart on superset.

The interaction with mouse clicks seems indeed to have changed (now I can select one or more cells and I see that their background color is changed). However, I cannot find a way to bind the filter event to the destination chart.

I would have expected to see my 'Table that emits filter events' listed in the left column of "Filter" menu, that appears after clicking on Edit Dashboard. However, in that configuration menu I can only find a list of "Filter box" charts on the left. Apparently, the Table is allowed to emit filter events, but it not recognized among the 'emitters' of events.

How can I bind the filter events, generated from my Table, to the charts that should be influenced by those events?

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure out why it wouldn't work?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I have no new suggestions on this one. In order to complete the use case, we eventually used a workaround (i.e., redesigning the objects on that dashboard to approximate the desired behavior).